# how to make countdown timer to disable the button for one day

Tags: android

I am developing a quiz app in it I retrieve one question per day date wise and the user has to answer only this retrieved question. I want to disable my button after user submitted his answer and it remains disabled until next day.

Comment: show your efforts

Comment: where is your effort? show us your effort first

Comment: Disable the button for one day ? Use `SharedPrefernce` to save the disabled time and resume the timer according to current time.

Comment: You may need help from server side to make it work perfectly

Comment: any sample code please..

Answer (score 0):

when user submit answer that time your button disable like using below code..

```
    myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

add also make one if condition like your date wise and also answer given by user that time invisible button you make one condition like ...

```
        if (question.date==currentDate && answer ==true)
        myButton.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    else
        myButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to start an one day period, save the current time in a SharedPreference:

```
 SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
 editor.putLong("time", currentTime);
 editor.apply();
 btn.setEnabled(false);
```

Then use this

```
SharedPreferences prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("time", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
long previousTime = prefs.getLong("time", 0);
long currentTime = new Date().getTime();
if (currentTime - previousTime > 24*60*60*1000){
//enable the button
btn.setEnabled(true);
} else {
//disable it and start a new CountdownTimer; this is needed in order for
//it to to become enabled if you're still in the app and the time ran out
btn.setEnabled(false);
 new CountDownTimer(currentTime - previousTime, 1000){
  public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
  btn.setText("fdfjhsn" + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
  }

 public void onFinish() {
     btn.setEnabled(true)
 }
 }.start();
```

Comment: when user click the button first time button get disabled and the click time is stored in a variable, and countdown get start and when time reaches 12:00 am button get enable automatically..

Comment: Then you have to fetch system time in each time interval and match with the stored time.